# How can I open the settings of a Firefox extension in a new tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

I change the customization settings of one of my Firefox extensions quite frequently. After a while it starts to get old going to the extensions list and finding a particular extension in my list of 50+ that's installed.

I notice that, instead of a popup window, some extension open their settings in a new tab. Ghostery, for instance:

[image]

If I can open the settings to an extension in a new tab, I can easily bookmark the URL or even bind it to a hotkey.

If it helps, my specific extension is [Tree style tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/).

Is it possible to open a settings dialog in a tab instead of as a popup window?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to write the url in the new tab's adress bar by your hand.
Or Maybe you can try find what is your extension opening in `about:config`and modify it.
(note: write `about:config` to the adress bar)